# What is the function of !! in front of an argument inside a function?

Tags: r, syntax

I am reviewing code that was given to me as part of a homework. I am familiar with functions in R, but this person is using !! before the 'y' argument inside the function, which I had never seen before. I am wondering what is the function of !!.

I have tried google and the help function in R studio.

```
my_table <- function(df = NULL, y = NULL, grp = NULL,
                           grpname = " ", dgts = 1, tbltitle = " ") {
  y <- enquo(y)
  grp <- enquo(grp)
  mysummary <- df %>% group_by(!!grp) %>% summarize(
    n = sum(!is.na(!!y)),
    mean = format(round(mean(!!y, na.rm=T), dgts), nsmall=dgts), 
    sd = format(round(sd(!!y, na.rm=T), dgts), nsmall=dgts),
    se = format(round(sd(!!y, na.rm=T)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(!!y))), dgts),
                nsmall=dgts),

  kable(mysummary)
}
```

Comment: It's part of what's called [tidyeval](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/) used in `dplyr` and related functions

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about this, but will look into it.